# Understanding all homomorphisms $\alpha: \mathbb{Z}^a \to \mathbb{Z}^b$ and their matrix representations

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I want to understand all possible homomorphisms $$\alpha: \mathbb{Z}^a \to \mathbb{Z}^b$$ as well as understand what a matrix representation for an arbitrary one of these homomorphisms would look like. Furthermore, under what conditions does a homomorphism have a matrix representation?

To begin, let $(e_1,e_2,......,e_a)$ be a bases for $\mathbb{Z}^a$ and $(f_1,f_2,......,f_b)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^b$.

And eh, yeah, can someone give me some insights into my inquiries? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just write $\alpha(e_j) = \sum_{i=1}^b m_{ij} f_i$ for each $j=1,\dots,a$.

Then, the matrix $M=(m_{ij})\in \mathbb Z^{b \times a}$ describes $\alpha$ in the sense that $[\alpha(v)]_f = M[v]_e$.

This works exactly as with linear maps between vector spaces.

Comment: Are your subscripts correct on this? It looks like there are only $a$ different $f's$

Comment: @MichaelVaughan, fixed, thanks.